# How to connect to Redis Cluster with ServiceStack client (without Sentinel)

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I setup a Redis Cluster (ver 3.2.0), not Sentinel, with 4 masters (each with a slave) and a Virtual IP randomly pointing to one of 4 Master servers' IPs.

VIP: 10.0.0.10:6379, connecting to M1, M2, M3, M4:

> M1: 10.0.0.1:6379 -
> S1: 10.0.0.5:6378
> M2: 10.0.0.2:6379 -
> S2: 10.0.0.6:6378
> M3: 10.0.0.3:6379 -
> S3: 10.0.0.7:6378
> M4: 10.0.0.4:6379 -
> S4: 10.0.0.8:6378

My client uses ServiceStack to connect to my cluster via VIP: 10.0.0.10:6379, but I get the error:

> An exception of type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException' occurred in ServiceStack.Redis.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: MOVED 2872 10.0.0.3:6379

My current string:

```xml
<add key="REDIS_MANAGER" value="redsAuthEnt@10.0.0.10:6379?connectTimeout=10000" />
```

I think this happens because my ServiceStack string connects as standalone Redis not a Redis Cluster.
It's the same as when we have to use `-c` with the `redis-cli` command line.

Help me craft a connection string to my Redis Cluster using the ServiceStack client or any other solution to use Redis Cluster.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack.Redis does not support Redis Cluster, you can vote for this [feature request on UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/7206222-create-an-object-that-supports-the-coming-redis-cl).

Comment: Thanks, I voted. But that topic have more than one year ago, the SericeStack.Redis current version is not yet supported Redis cluster?

Comment: No it doesn't support Redis cluster, that feature request would be closed otherwise.

Comment: Thanks mythz . Do you know other client which support Redis cluster?

Comment: @TuanPham checkout [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis#features)